# Android Keystore - can a user key be retrieved by root if he setuid to that user?

Tags: android, security, encryption, android-keystore

Since Android 4.3, Android has its own keystore where I can store keys and use them later for encryption/decryption.

It is said [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#43-enterprise-security) that each key can only be retrieved by its owner and not even root can get it.

My question is: 
Couldn't I write a program that would switch my uid to the owner of the key, retrieve it, and then use it to decrypt data I shouldn't have access to?

Edit: Added citation to keystore doc.

Comment: "It is said that ..." citation?

Answer (score 5):

It is true that normally a key can only be retrieved by the user that stored it.

See e.g.: http://nelenkov.blogspot.se/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html

If a device is rooted, the keys still cannot be retrieved unless the attacker also has the password.

If the attacker has rooted the device and has the password or the device is unlocked, it's game over.

Comment: When the device is in the After First Unlock (AFU) state, the device (from the perspective of the OS) is unencrypted. At this point, root doesn't need the user's credentials. Saying "the keys still cannot be retrieved unless the attacker also has the password" is not true. Once the device is decrypted (i.e. in AFU), root has full access to the KeyStore.

Answer (score 5):

Its been a while since the original post, so the content in the links may have changed.

The [first link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) doesn't mention anything about root. But it does mention:

> If the Android OS is compromised or an attacker can read the device's internal storage, the attacker may be able to use any app's Android Keystore keys on the Android device, **but not extract them from the device**.

This may sound contradictive: how can an attacker use the KeyStore keys without "extract[ing] them from the device"? This gets to the core of what the Android KeyStore is for.

One of the major properties about the Android KeyStore is that it is separate from the OS, through the use of Trusted Execution Environment (TEE). So, if an attacker could compromise the OS, then they couldn't compromise the *contents* of the KeyStore (this isn't true in the case of a software-backed KeyStore). The KeyStore securely stores the keys and (at the request of the OS) encrypts/decrypts data using those keys. If an attacker is able to compromise the OS, then the attacker is also able to request the KeyStore to decrypt previously encrypted data on the device. The important property is that the attacker never actually "sees" the keys themselves; meaning the attacker cannot decrypt data that is stored *off* the device.

The [second link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#43-enterprise-security) says:

> This provides a place to create or store private keys that cannot be exported off the device, even in the event of a root or kernel compromise.

This echoes back what I said before. A malicious program with root is unable to physically "export" the keys off the device. However, this does not mean that the program is unable to request the KeyStore to decrypt data stored on the device.

To answer your question:

> Couldn't I write a program that would switch my uid to the owner of the key, retrieve it, and then use it to decrypt data I shouldn't have access to?

With root, you can essentially do anything that is not restricted in hardware. There is some exception to this with SELinux. But otherwise, I don't see a reason why root can't do so. This is backed by the answers to:

- [Is android keystore still vulnerable if root access is received?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153361/is-android-keystore-still-vulnerable-if-root-access-is-received)

> An application with root access has full control over the system and can do whatever it wants to do because it can override all (DAC type *) security restrictions. So the short answer is "yes".

- [How to crack (get secret from) Android Keystore System](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124764/how-to-crack-get-secret-from-android-keystore-system)

> Any app with root privileges can impersonate other apps and have their sensitive data decrypted or signed by the keystore by issuing a legitimate request on behalf of other apps and system.

- [Android - What are the practical security benefits of using a hardware-backed keystore vs software-only keystore vs no keystore](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201068/android-what-are-the-practical-security-benefits-of-using-a-hardware-backed-ke)

> The purpose of a key store is not to restrict access to an application or application data, it's purpose is to protect the credential from being exposed during use. Since a key store will willingly leverage its knowledge to encrypt data or access sensitive application information, it's not really a challenge for an attacker to leverage as you pointed out in many of your breakdowns across all three types.

- [Android Kernel Security](https://source.android.com/security/overview/kernel-security)

> Encrypting data with a key stored on-device does not protect the application data from root users. Applications can add a layer of data protection using encryption with a key stored off-device, such as on a server or a user password. This approach can provide temporary protection while the key is not present, but at some point the key must be provided to the application and it then becomes accessible to root users.

The last point is meant for a more generic treatment of the problem. If an attacker has root, it is essentially impossible to defend against. Encryption won't stop the attacker because either the attacker can directly find the encryption key on the device, request a hardware backed solution to decrypt the data for it, or wait for the application to decrypt the data itself and then root can dump the process's memory and get access to the unencrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

> "Couldn't I write a program that would switch my uid to the owner of the key, retrieve it, and then use it to decrypt data I shouldn't have access to?"

UIDs are assigned to individual applications at install time. An Android application cannot change its UID.

Comment: What stops root from executing a process as a different UID?

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of Android are using a [Hardware Keystore or StrongBox Keymaster](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#HardwareSecurityModule). I.e. a compromised device can use the key, but not extract the key material. The whole secure computation is done in a dedicated secure environment.

Since Android 6 a hardware key store is offered, e.g. using a TEE (trusted execution environment, i.e. special isolated CPU area), since Android 9 StrongBox which would be a dedicated secure element, i.e. special chip.
The key must be stored in a  way to support this, i.e. the developer has to pay attention storing the key securely by.

The [Android Compatibility Definition for Android 9](https://source.android.com/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd#9_11_keys_and_credentials) is requiring at least a TEE implementation.

Depending on your phone when looking into "Settings -> Security -> Encryption & details -> Storage type" a high level information can be seen, if the phone supports any kind of these features.